# PrintWriter not writing to file in java

Tags: java, printwriter

Please can someone advise if there is anything wrong with this code? It doesn't write anything to the file

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class writeToFile {
    static String filename = "te.txt";
      public static void recorder()
        {
            try
            {   
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
                int me = 1232132;
                writer.write(me);
                System.out.println("Written");
                writer.close();
    
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error when writing file");
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        recorder();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look for the the file "te.txt" in the current directory

Comment: @Joe - you mean the directory where my writeToFile program is right? I dont see anything there for te.txt

Comment: Not really. It depends on your environment you are working with. The IDE usually has it weird settings. Just move to a CMD window and run "java WriteToFile" and see what happens.

Comment: @Joe - you are absolutely right. I traversed back up a few folders from the path where the program was and found the file! Thank you so much.